# Parsing arrays in req.body in node js express facing issue

Tags: node.js, express

I am getting an array in request body like (Get method) :

```
Array(1)[
0: {BuildNumber: ""10.0.0.10""}
]
```

I want buildNumber value to pass into the query .

```
 router.get("/GetTfsItem",function(req,res,next){

    console.log( "param   :" + req.body);

    }
```

When I am trying to print req.body it shows 
param   :[object Object]

and If I am trying to print req.body.BuildNumber it shows as undefined .

Please help me to resolve this

Comment: Try `JSON.parse(req.body)` before printing it

Comment: unexpected token o in json at position 1 getting this error when trying to parsse

Answer (score 0):

Your `req.body` is array of objects and not just objects so you need to loop through that:

```
router.get("/GetTfsItem", function(req, res, next) {
  req.body.forEach((obj) => {
    console.log("param: ", obj.BuildNumber);
  });
})
```

Comment: req.body.forEach is not a function  getting this error

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the JSON body using express middleware:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.json()) // << This line

app.get('/GetTfsItem', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body)
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Now if you send a request with a JSON body, like this:

```
GET /GetTfsItem HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "some": [ "foo", "bar" ]
}
```

Then `console.log(req.body.some[0])` will output `foo`